# Export isochrones to images

Tags: geojson

I'm looking for automated/scripted ways to generate PNG images based on GeoJSON multi-polygons.

I have multiple polygon isochrones for a given starting point, e.g. 10 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 minutes, etc. These are generated in GeoJSON format. Are there any techniques for *automating* the generation of an output like [this](http://geoseyeview.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/public_transit_time_from_dtta.png)?

i.e. I want to be able to generate this type of colourful PNG maps automatically, as I have over 1000 to do.

Comment: What a nice looking hex-grid!